# Efficiently searching 2D Matrix for multiple items

Tags: java, algorithm, search

I have a 25x25 grid that looks like this. Across the grid there are two randoms sequences of strings placed and I'm trying to develop a couple of efficient ways to search through the grid and find the points of each location.

[image]

I've looked through a couple of examples of algorithms that search through a 2D array and most seemed to be focused on finding a single character or number among others.

What kind of options do I have for searching in this particular instance? I've implemented a basic step at a time search like this:

```
public void search(String[][] grid) {
    int cellsSearched = 0;
    List<Point> cLocations = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Point> sLocations = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            if (cLocations.size() == 5 && sLocations.size() == 3) break;
            if (grid[i][j].equals("S")) {
                sLocations.add(new Point(i, j));
            } else if (grid[i][j].equals("C")) {
                cLocations.add(new Point(i, j));
            }
            cellsSearched++;
        }
    }
}
```

But this clearly is not the most efficient way to search.

I've thought of splitting the grid into quadrants and searching a quadrant at a time, but this still seems like it has too many potential flaws. (ex. Both sequences are located in the last quadrant that is searched).

My question is, how can I search this grid in the least amount of steps possible and gather the coordinates for each character in its sequence?

Comment: Since you have _no_ prior information on which to base your search on, you will have to visit every cell in the grid at least once -- even if you want to build some sort of index which can optimize searches and lookups. Besides, if your grid is going to be that small, there is no reason to look for optimizations because they wouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: @EvilTak I'm not sure I have to visit every cell once. The size of "C" is always 5 long and the size of "S" is always 3 long. So I know I can stop when their relative ArrayLists are the correct size. Also, I'm aware that there's really no point in optimizing something like this. But my question was how can I reduce the amount of total steps it takes to find all the locations. Sure it doesn't really make a difference, but that's not the point here.

Comment: WIll the 'C's and 'S's always be in rows?

Comment: @harman786 no they can also be columns

Comment: If you know that shortest sequence has length 3, you can check only diagonals with step 3 (the first one (2,0)-(0,2). then (5,0)-(0,5) etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one trick you can use to improve the runtime of the search. 
But because it is a grid, and because we have no information about the placements of the `'S'` and `'C'` whatsoever, the time complexity will remain `O(n^2)`.
With that out of the way,
Once you hit either `'S'` or `'C'` you actually can store the whole sequence of them from right there. You basically have to check whether there is that same character on either side of the current character and continue. 
You can have an extra `2D` array of `boolean` which keep tracks of which points are included in the `ArrayList`.
 Here is the code to get the better idea:

```
public void search(String[][] grid) {
    int cellsSearched = 0;
    List<Point> cLocations = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Point> sLocations = new ArrayList<>();

    boolean[][] map = new boolean[grid.length][grid[0].length];

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            if (cLocations.size() == 5 && sLocations.size() == 3) break;
            if(!map[i][j]) {
                if (grid[i][j].equals("S")) {
                    getSeries(i, j, "S", grid, map, sLocations);
                } else if (grid[i][j].equals("C")) {
                    getSeries(i, j, "C", grid, map, sLocations);
                }
            }
            cellsSearched++;
        }
    }
}

public boolean inbounds(int i, int j, String[][] grid) {
    return ( 0 <= i && i < grid.length ) && ( 0 <= j && j < grid[i].length );
}

public void getSeries(int i, int j, String toFind,String[][] grid, boolean map[][], ArrayList<Point> locations) {

    /**
     * This function basically checks if 'i' and 'j' are safe so that accessing grid[i][j]
     * would not cause ArrayOutOfBoundsException
     */
    if(!inbounds(i, j, grid)) {
        return;
    }

    String matched = grid[i][j];
    if(!map[i][j] && matched.equals(toFind)) {
        map[i][j] = true;
        locations.add(new Point(i, j));

        // Going up
        getSeries(i - 1, j, toFind, grid, map, locations);

        // Going down
        getSeries(i + 1, j, toFind, grid, map, locations);

        // Going left
        getSeries(i, j - 1, toFind, grid, map, locations);

        // Going right
        getSeries(i, j + 1, toFind, grid, map, locations);

        /*
        (i+1, j-1) -> Going Bottom Left
        (i+1, j+1) -> Going Bottom Right

        (i-1, j-1) -> Going Top Left
        (i-1, j+1) -> Going Top Right 
        */
    }
}
```

You see once you hit either `'S'` or `'C'` the `getSeries` function will automatically save the whole sequence to the `ArrayList`.

As I mentioned earlier, the time complexity is still `O(n^2)` but it will surely reduce the number of steps to find the sequence.

Comment: Can you expand a bit more on the `inbouds` function. Is the intention to check whether the calculations performed below on `i` and/or `j` are beyond the bounds of the grid? An implementation would be helpful. Also, some locations can be placed vertically. Am I just able to add 4 more recursive calls to get series with the vertical locations you mentioned in your bottom comments?

Comment: Yeah, I have edited the answer. It includes `inbounds` implementation. I have added some comments that will make it more clear about the directions